# How to determine require source?

Tags: node.js

Is it real to determine from where module was required?

For example, we have 2 files: `parent.js`, `child.js`

In `parent.js` we `require('child.js')`.

I am looking for feature to use in `child.js` to determine that "I" was required from `parent.js` and its path.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the caller via `module.parent`. In the actual module (the one required) put this:

```js
console.log("required at:", module.parent.filename)
```

It will tell you the path of the file which required the module.

Here are the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent).